# Pentaho Data Integration - Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, pentaho, etl, kafka-consumer-api, pdi

I am using the Kafka Consumer Plugin for Pentaho CE and would appreciate your help in its usage. I would like to know if any of you were in a situation where pentaho failed and you lost any messages (based on the official docs there's no way to read the message twice, am I wrong ?). If this situation occurs how do you capture these messages so you can reprocess them?

reference:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Apache+Kafka+Consumer

Answer (score 0):

Kafka retains messages for the configured retention period whether they've been consumed or not, so it allows consumers to go back to an offset they previously processed and pick up there again.

I haven't used the Kafka plugin myself, but it looks like you can disable auto-commit and manage that yourself. You'll probably need the Kafka system tools from Apache and some command line steps in the job. You'd have to fetch the current offset at the start, get the last offset from the messages you consume and if the job/batch reaches the finish, commit that last offset to the cluster.

It could be that you can also provide the starting offset as a field (message key?) to the plugin, but I can't find any documentation on what that does. In that scenario, you could store the offset with your destination data and go back to the last offset there at the start of each run. A failed run wouldn't update the destination offset, so would not lose any messages.

If you go the second route, pay attention to the auto.offset.reset setting and behavior, as it may happen that the last offset in your destination has already disappeared from the cluster if it's been longer than the retention period.